# How can I download data from NYC open data into GIS?

Tags: coordinate-system, data, united-states

I have a data from NYC open data website and I need to download them to GIS so it will be easier to analyze
https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Motor-Vehicle-Collisions/h9gi-nx95

How can I open and explore data from NYC open data into GIS when I only have longitude and latitude figures, and there is no coordination system given?

Comment: You can assume it is WGS84, EPSG:4326. What "GIS" are you using?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @AMK! Export the data as csv, then in your GIS software import the csv as delimited text file assigning the revelant lat and lon fields. Chances are the coordinate system would be in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

Answer (score 1):

There is an option on the website available to download the data into csv file. You can download the data into csv file and then add that csv file into GIS Sotware ( ESRI ArcGIS, QGIS) . There are set of tools available that can be used to display that data as points on map. e.g in ArcGIS there is tool Display XY data available that can be used to display them on map.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [SODA 2.1 API](https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofnewyork.us/qiz3-axqb) for that dataset, you can also export it as GeoJSON:  https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/qiz3-axqb/rows.geojson

I'd try that. It'll be in the WGS84 projection.